# Segmentation fault while running Java with old GLIBC

Tags: dependencies, glibc

I am trying to run `Java 1.7.0_21-b11` with `GLIBC 2.3.6`. Java 7 requires at least `GLIBC 2.4`.

I've tried [this](http://www.forkit.org/~bmoore/hidi/tags/programming/) solution, so using ldd, I've found the following dependencies:

```
ld-2.7.so
ld-linux.so.2
libc.so.6
libdl.so.2
libpthread.so.0
```

I've copied these files (along with `ld-2.7.so`) from similar but newer system (both are Slackware), and tried to invoke java with preloaded libraries, but I got a segfault:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD="./ld-linux.so.2 ./libc.so.6 ./libd l.so.2 ./libpthread.so.0" ./ld-2.7.so /usr/lib/java_new/bin/java
Segmentation fault
```

I'm a bit stuck so any advice how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - running Java on a build server running on an old Ubuntu.

I've installed all required libraries in a folder and used LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to them. It did not work. I think that the problem was that glibc is not compatible with the kernel.

The solution was to install a new Linux distribution and migrate the build server to the new Ubuntu.